# Is there always a prime number between $p_n^2$ and $p_{n+1}^2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The following table indicates that there is a prime number p between the square of two consecutive primes.

$$
\displaystyle
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 \text{n} & p_n^2 & p_{n+1}^2 & \text{p} \\
\hline
 1 & 4 & 9 & 7 \\
 2 & 9 & 25 & 23 \\
 3 & 25 & 49 & 47 \\
 4 & 49 & 121 & 113 \\
 5 & 121 & 169 & 167 \\
 6 & 169 & 289 & 283 \\
 7 & 289 & 361 & 359 \\
 8 & 361 & 529 & 523 \\
 9 & 529 & 841 & 839 \\
 10 & 841 & 961 & 953
\end{array}
$$

> Can anyone prove that for each natural number $n$ there is always a prime number $p$, such that $p_n^2<p<p_{n+1}^2$ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe. Can we prove it? The answer has to be no. Since there may be an infinite number of primes $p_{n+1}-p_n = 2,$ and since we cannot now prove that there is a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+2)^2$ for all n, the answer seems clear-cut.

Comment: +1 Of course, we wouldn't need to prove the existence of a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+2)^2$ for all $n$, but yes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I could go back and edit but I think your comment covers it,thanks.

Comment: There is a conjecture called Brocard's conjecture that there always exist 4 primes between $p_n^2$ and $p_{n+1}^2$, which is still unresolved. This seems easier, so there might be some hope of existing a proof for this conjecture.

Comment: You are taking the use of oppersman conjecture?

Answer (score 6):

This is a famous unsolved problem called Legendre's conjecture. It's 'obviously' true but very hard to prove. In some sense it is stronger than the Riemann Hypothesis (which only 'gets you' $\sqrt x\log x$ instead of $2\sqrt x$), so I wouldn't expect it to be proved soon.

Comment: Legendre would imply the OP, but is the converse true?

Comment: @daniel: Oh, you're right -- I missed (somehow) the subtlety that the question applies only to prime squares.

Answer (score 0):

This question is Brocard's conjecture. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_conjecture.